# Пропала возможность скролить контент в ScrollRect с помощью Drag'n'Drop

Tags: c#, unity3d-editor

Раньше работал и скроллинг мышью и Drag'n'Drop для премещения контента. После какого-то времени, заметил, что Drag'n'Drop перестал работать и в эдиторе и после компиляции в apk, на телефоне. Скриптами не трогал эти элементы. Scroll View создается в эдиторе.

Если **дублировать** сцену, удалить с неё Scroll View и потом создать заново, то ничего не изменится. А вот если создать **новую** сцену и сделать в ней такой же Scroll View, то Drag'n'Drop в ней работает как и должен.

Баг эдитора или какие-то настройки сцены поломались, может что-то с ивентом "OnBeginDrag", что он не срабатывает, не могу понять. Не хочется создавать новую сцену и в ней заново создавать все элементы, чтобы Drag'n'Drop заработал. Может какие-то настройки на дефолт сбросить нужно?

P.S Если скопировать Canvas со сцены где не работает Drag'n'Drop, в новую, чистую сцену, то всё начинает работать.
Так же, если в новой сцене выключить объект EventSystem(он автоматом создается эдитором), то помимо Drag'n'Drop перестаёт работать ещё и прокрутка колёсиком мыши.
Пробовал копировать EventSystem из новой сцены(где всё работает), в основную, но тоже никакого эффекта.

Мне кажется, это как-то связанно с работой EventSystem. Почему в основной сцене он не хочет обрабатывать событие  Drag'n'Drop, а при создании новой сцены - всё работает.

Answer (score 0):

Баг вызывался камерой. Создал новую камеру, прикрепил её к Canvas и всё чудом заработало. Хотя настройки новой и старой камеры абсолютно одинаковые.